# Cast/Convert nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-tuning

i have table:

```
id   timestamp
1    31.10.2020 16:32:11
2    09.09.2020 09:15:49
3    22.04.2020 02:48:15
```

Table have huge amount these data. Column timestamp is data type "nvarchar". And i need to sort datas by date or use in clauses WHERE for constraint by date, so i need to convert "timestamp" to datetime. But I can't. I tried convert and cast but still failed.

Any advice?

Thx.

Comment: The real solution here is fix your design; `nvarchar` is not for storing dates.

Comment: Of course, you better fix the datamodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your design, and change the column to a date and time data type. Considering your data is accurate to 1 second, a `datetime2(0)` seems appropriate here. First we need to change the "format" of the `nvarchar` value to an ISO format. We're going to use the ISO8601 format (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm) as it's unambiguous:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET [timestamp] = CONVERT(nvarchar(20),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), [timestamp], 4), 126);
```

Now you can `ALTER` the table and change the data type to a `datetime2(0)`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN [timestamp] datetime2(0) NULL;
```

I also recommend using a different name than `timestamp` for your column. `timestamp` is a **deprecated** synonym for `rowversion`, so it's use can make it quite confusing; especially as `rowversion` is not a date and time value but a `binary` value and *cannot* be converted to a date and time data type.

Comment: If I follow the above procedure, I will have  only NULL in the column, right?

Comment: Only values that *failed* to be converted would be `NULL`, @Cesc; but then the date wasn't valid in the first place, the data would be meaningless.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. My fault. I think, that  the format after a minute is not important. My column looks exactly like this: '12.01.20 15:34:34, 000000000 EUROPE/PRAGUE' . I exported the oracle table therefore these problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly convert to a `datetime` using [`convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) format 104:

```
select convert(datetime, '31.10.2020 16:32:11', 104)
```