# Cast/Convert nvarchar to datetime(2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-tuning

Since I described it poorly last time, again

i have table:

```
id   time_stamp
1    12.01.20 15:34:34,000000000 EUROPE/PRAGUE
2    10.01.20 10:15:15,000000000 EUROPE/PRAGUE
3    09.01.20 05:55:42,000000000 EUROPE/PRAGUE
```

Table have huge amount these data. Column timestamp is data type "nvarchar". And i need to sort datas by date or use in clauses WHERE for constraint by date, so i need to convert "timestamp" to datetime. But I can't. I tried convert and cast but still failed.

From @Larnu i got advice, but didnt work, because I'm stupid and inaccurately described the problem.

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET [timestamp] = CONVERT(nvarchar(20),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), [timestamp], 104), 126);
```

Now you can ALTER the table and change the data type to a datetime2(0):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN [timestamp] datetime2(0) NULL;
```

any advice on how to change with respect to the time_stamp column.

Thx.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64154892/2029983)? Just remove the `',00000...'` portion of your string. You can easily achieve that with `LEFT`.

Comment: @Larnu When i used UPDATE my_table
SET time_stamp =
    LEFT(time_stamp, LEN(timestamp)-24)  and then your 'UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET [timestamp] = CONVERT(nvarchar(20),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), [timestamp], 104), 126)' so i have same NULL

Comment: Apologies, by bad for assuming you had `yyyy`, use `4`. I have updated my prior answer

Comment: Well I say I *assumed* it ***was*** `yyyy` in your last question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast/Convert nvarchar to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154892/cast-convert-nvarchar-to-datetime)