# Spark sql convert string 000000 to 00:00:00 timestamp datatype

Tags: sql, string, apache-spark-sql, casting, timestamp

I have a field with datatype string which has values like this: '000000'. I need to convert this to datatype timestamp and should look like this : 00:00:00.

Does anyone know how to do this transformation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show what would be the input for 01:00:00 ?

Comment: Similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154892/cast-convert-nvarchar-to-datetime

Comment: It seems what you need is `interval`, not `timestamp`

Comment: the input for 01:00:00 would be 010000

Comment: Would you know how to convert to interval datatype?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a formatted string you can use the following code:

```
select regexp_replace('000000','^(..)(..)(..)$','$1:$2:$3') as time_string
```

| time_string |
| --- |
| 00:00:00 |

If you want something you could actually work with, use the following code to get interval type:

```
select cast(regexp_replace('000000','(..)(..)(..)','$1:$2:$3') as interval hour to second) as hour_to_second_interval
```

| hour_to_second_interval |
| --- |
| {"zero": false, "seconds": 0, "negative": false, "nano": 0, "units": ["SECONDS", "NANOS"]} |

P.S.
000000 is probably the worst example you could come with....